# Angular $http returning new values only once

Tags: codeigniter, rest, angularjs

I am new to Angular, and set up a simple example with a REST Api config in Codeigniter that returns a json (default) thread list.  No problems!

Until, I add an update to the Database.  If I clear/then call `getThreads` again, I receive the same list of items.  A page refresh solves this.  I can see in firebug that its only calling the `url:api/example/threadlist/id/'x'` once per page load.

```
function ThreadsCtrl($scope, $http, $templateCache) {
    $scope.getThreads = function(id) {
        if (!id) { id = 'reset'; }
        $http({method: 'GET', url: 'api/example/threadlist/id/' + id, cache: $templateCache}).
            success(function(data) {
                $scope.threadslist = data;                  //set view model
            }).
            error(function(data) {
                $scope.threadslist = data || "Request failed";
            });
  };
```

How would I make it so that it always calls a new list of data rather than reuses the old.

Thanks!

Comment: why dont u remove cache:$templatecache from your ajax call

Comment: duh!  thanks. So easy to overlook things like that when you are copying / pasting code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understood your question correctly your ajax call is being cached so you have to remove cache:$templatecache from your code